# OCaml - If then else

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

I want to do several things inside a if then else.
I read a string and then I check it's lenght. If it's 3 it does X, if it's 4 it does Y.

I tried:

```
let str = read_line ()

let first_approach () =
    if String.lenght str = 3
    then let    char1 = String.get str 0
         let    char2 = String.get str 1
         let    char3 = String.get str 2
    else ()

let second_approach () =
    if String.lenght str = 3
    then let    char1 = String.get str 0
         let    char2 = String.get str 1
         let    char3 = String.get str 2
         let    char4 = String.get str 3
    else ()
```

I want to know how to make all things inside *then* work. Because I get *Syntax error*.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with this code.

At the outermost level of a module (e.g., a source file or REPL input), you can use `let var = val` to define a global variable. In your code you're using this construct to define `str`, for example.

However, whenever `let` appears anywhere else (inside a declaration or expression) it is used to define a *local* variable, and must be followed by `in` and the expression in which the local definition is used. Since you don't have `in` in your definitions of `first_approach` and `second_approach`, your code isn't syntactically valid.

Since the definitions inside `first_approach` and `second_approach` are local, there will be no effect after you call them. The definitions for `char1` and so on, even if syntactically corrected, won't be global. (As @melpomene says, the code doesn't do anything.)

If you have several expressions separated by `;` you can use `begin` / `end` to group them into one expression after `then` or `else`.

```
let f x =
    if x > 5 then
        begin
        Printf.printf "x is quite large\n";
        Printf.printf "adios\n"
        end
```

If a string `s` is of length 3, there is no character `String.get s 3`.

```
# let s = "abc";;
val s : string = "abc"
# String.get s 3;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds".
```

Comment: Then how can I do it? I don't want to create 4 char variables if the string has only 3 lenght.

Comment: You need to think about the problem differently. For example, instead of using `char1` you can just say `str.[0]` throughout the rest of your code. You already have all the characters where you can access them. (Note that `str.[0]` is equivalent to `String.get str 0`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple variables in a single let using

```
let (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
```

Or using your string example:

```
let (char1, char2, char3, char4_opt) =
    if String.lenght str = 3
    then (str.[0], str.[1], str.[2], None)
    else (str.[0], str.[1], str.[2], Some str.[3])
```

Note: I used char4_opt with an option type because there is nothing to put in there for length 3 strings.

Comment: let char1, char2, char3, char4_opt = (str.[0], str.[1], str.[2], ( if String.lenght str < 4 then None else Some str.[3]) )